# Unable to dispatch two actions within effect in rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, store

I am dispatching two actions and no need to execute sequentially. I tried below code:

```
 @Effect()
   loadIntResponse$ = 
   this.actions.ofType(fromActions.LOAD_INT_RESPONSE).pipe(
   switchMap(() => {
     return this.Service.int().pipe(
    tap(x => this.store.dispatch(new fromActions.LoadService(x))),
    map(responseResult => {
     return new fromActions.LoadIntResponseSuccess(responseResult)
    }),
    catchError(error => {
      let err: responseResult = {
        status: "FALSE",
        message: error
      }
      return of(new fromActions.LoadIntResponseFail(err))
    })
  )
 })
)

loadService$ = this.actions.ofType(fromActions.Load_Service).pipe(
    switchMap((action: fromActions.LoadService) => {
    if (action.payload.status == 'TRUE' {
    return this.reuseService.reuseServiceCall().pipe(
    map( result ==> {
        return of({type: fromActions.LOAD_SERVICE_SUCCESS, payload: 
        result})
   }),
   catchError(error => {
      let err: responseResult = {
        status: "FALSE",
        message: error
      }
      return of(new fromActions.LoadServiceFail(err))
    })
  )
 })
)
```

But it is not triggering another effect LoadService()

**Expected Result:** Trigger another effect LoadService()

LoadService accept any type parameter.

I really appreciate for the help. Thank you!

Comment: What is this effect supposed to do? And the return in your catchError most likely wont work.

Comment: which effect LoadService()?

Comment: No, just the code Im looking at

Comment: This effect suppose to call the service.int() which will return status and message. If success then LoadIntResponseSuccess with response result from service.int() and trigger another effect LoadService(x). x being response result as well from service call this.Service.int(). Otherwise, in the catch call fail action passing the response result, status as FALSE and error message in message.

Comment: Ok, thats not how it works! Basically you want to dispatch new fromActions.LoadService(x) when fromActions.LoadIntResponseSuccess happens?

Comment: Yes you are correct. But I am checking the result of this.service.int() status in LoadService(x) so I can trigger it when there is no catchError only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some modification to match what you said you wanted in the comments. First you have an effect that calls `int()` then will dispatch a `LoadIntResponseSuccess` if successful but will go to the `catchError` if not. You have a second effect that listen to `LoadIntResponseSuccess` and will dispatch a `LoadService` as soon as `LoadIntResponseSuccess`  is triggered.

I could be wrong with the second effect because I dont know how the format of the data passed with your action so `x` could be `x.something`

The loadService effect is now filtering the payload first. You cant have a if in a `switchMap` that allow you to return something or nothing, you have to have an else if you want an if! After the filtering, the service called is made and if its successful, `LoadServiceSuccess` is dispatched if not, it goes to the `catchError`.

```
 @Effect()
   loadIntResponse$ = 
   this.actions.ofType(fromActions.LOAD_INT_RESPONSE).pipe(
   switchMap(() => this.Service.int()),
   map((responseResult) => new fromActions.LoadIntResponseSuccess(responseResult)),
   catchError((error: any, effects: Observable<Action>) => {
      let err: responseResult = {
        status: "FALSE",
        message: error
      }
      return effect.pipe(startWith(new fromActions.LoadIntResponseFail(err)))
    })
  )

 @Effect()
   loadIntResponseSuccess$ = 
   this.actions.ofType(fromActions.LOAD_INT_RESPONSE_SUCCESS).pipe(
   map((action) => new fromActions.LoadService(action.payload))
  )



 @Effect()
    loadService$ = this.actions.ofType(fromActions.Load_Service).pipe(
       switchMap((action) => { if (action.payload.status === 'TRUE') {
         return [new fromActions.LoadServiceSuccess(action)]
        } else {
         return [new fromActions.LoadServiceFail()]
        } ),
         catchError((error: any, effects: Observable<Action>) => {
           let err: responseResult = {
             status: "FALSE",
             message: error
           }
           return effect.pipe(startWith(new 
             fromActions.LoadServiceFail(err)))
         })
       )
```

Comment: I updated the question above as per your queries earlier. If your answer works for it

Comment: @CodeVenture im not sure if your loadService effect is working but the rest should be fine or really close to be, the loadService effect will be reach but I cant say if the rest is correct.

Comment: I will let you know in a bit. I think I have to correct my loadService as well as per your suggestion.

Comment: @CodeVenture I added the loadService effect modifications, the object format can be wrong(the payload) but im doing it by heart so its hard without any kind of type checking. You should also start typing everything!

Comment: one question, what happens on loadService$ if in filter action.payload.status is not equal to TRUE? @ukn Thanks.

Comment: Nothing happens, that the point otherwise you would need a else that returns NEVER

Comment: But I need else statement where I call the LoadServiceFail as well.

Comment: That's not how it works either, catchError won't be called unless there is an http error here, with your code it wouldnt have done what you wanted. What you want is to dispatch loadservicefail if not true?

Comment: Yes, I want to dispatch loadservicefail if not true because I have to call final service if status is false and also having http error which is handled by catchError block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216591/discussion-between-codeventure-and-ukn).

Comment: I am not getting the payload value in loadService$

Comment: well debug the effect to see where its lost